# I am using lightsail and route53 to deploy my site, But bad request 400 is appear

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, dns, amazon-lightsail

I am using nginx and gunicorn server

And i followed steps of the aws docs and other's blog,
But Always face this error message
[image]

My nginx setting is
[image]

when trying

sudo systemctl status nginx
[image]

And my instance's settings here

[image]

I made A record and here's nameserver is
[image]

updated here
[image]

And i add records in hosting area
[image]

I had a very hard time to handle this...
What am i do?

Comment: When I go to `predict-chrun.com`, it says **Bad Request (400)**. However, if I go to `3.35.86.237`, it redirects to `http://3.35.86.237/blog/`. Both requests are successfully getting to the server, so the domain name and network is configured correctly. However, it appears that the web server has a bad Virtual Host configuration?

Comment: Thank you so much...  I will check about that